# How to create a React JS object from a CSV File (CSV Parsing/Papaparse)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, papaparse

I cannot figure out how to parse a CSV file into an array which can be displayed in React JS.

I tried using PapaParse and react-papaparse, but neither allowed me to return the csv as an array.

This is essential in React JS because the way components are created is by returning them from a function.

In the examples for Papaparse and react-papaparse, they merely write the array to the console, but you cannot return the value of the array from the function because they use their `complete` keyword to read the array and call the handler function rather than simply allowing you to parse the CSV to an array which can be stored in a variable.

Please provide a working example of how I can parse a CSV file to an array which I can return from a function and thus add to my react virtual dom.

Comment: I don’t know how to help you with your specific problem, but ignoring PHP for a moment, do you have a working example of React consuming a (presumably) JSON array over (presumably) HTTP? From there, can you generate the JSON in PHP, still ignoring CSV?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the solution is to use the `setState()` react js function in order to update the property you would like to in the function that is specified in the papaparse `complete` section.

Comment: Do you have a code example you can post here?